# Does windows 8 apps listview support subitems?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a dynamically created `listview` that contains 4 `stackpanels` for each item. In each `stackpanel` I have `textblocks` with data that I need to access. However, `yourListView.SelectedItems[row_Index].SubItems[col_index].Text` is not working. ther is no `SubItems` option. How would I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the WPF listview
and yes Stackpanels dont have the property subItems you need to call it like this:

`yourListView.SelectedItems[row_Index].Children[col_index].Text`

Comment: Getting this error: `Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`